# How do I get rid of everything, every string before a specified word in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, string

I'm trying to do a simple string replace in jquery but it seems to be more than just a simple code.
In **mygallery** have this image link (note the 2x ../)

```
var imgName= '../../appscripts/imgs/pic_library/burn.jpg';
```

In **browsegallery** I have something like this:

```
var imgName ='../../../../../appscripts/imgs/pic_library/burn.jpg';
```

and sometimes depending on where do I get the image source from, it can be like this

```
var imgName = '../appscripts/imgs/pic_library/burn.jpg';
```

What I'm trying to do is, to get rid of all of those '../', and to gain the imgName like this:

```
'appscripts/imgs/pic_library/burn.jpg';
```

So this way I can get the right directory for my mobile app.

Can anyone help me on how to get rid of all those (without even counting) '../'?

Best Regards!

Comment: This isn't a jquery problem.  It's a javascript problem.  Do you have any examples of anything you've tried?  If all you are trying to do is remove leading '../' then a simple regex replace is fairly easy.

Comment: @Taplar Yes, as I said, depending on where I access the image, it gives me the full path  with '../' 
In my final script I want to clean every '../'  and insert only the rest of the name
Thank you for helping me

Comment: @DuliNini why not use the `javascript` **replace()** function?

Comment: You could use ```String.split()``` something like: ```var imageDirectory = "appscripts" + imgName.split("appscripts")[1];```

Comment: Using **split()** will also work & **pop()** to return the last item in the array which will be the expected output. - `'../../../../../appscripts/imgs/pic_library/burn.jpg'.split('../').pop();`

Comment: Do you have access to whatever that is creating those paths?

Comment: @Varinder thank you that worked :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the replace method of a string you can remove all cases of the 
    ../

```
var imgPath = '../../../../../appscripts/imgs/pic_library/burn.jpg';
var imgName = imgPath.replace(/\.\.\//g, '');
console.log(imgName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct answer to your question that does not tie you to the "/appscripts" in your example:

```js
const imgName= '../../appscripts/imgs/pic_library/burn.jpg';
const img = imgName.split('../')
  .filter((val) => val !== '')
  .join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the desired end path is always the same - just get the unique part (the actual file name) and add it to a string of the path you require. the following usies lastIndexOf to get the actual file name from the relative path and then builds a string to give the desired path plus the file name.

```js
var fileSource = 'appscripts/imgs/pic_library/burn.jpg';
let lastIndex = fileSource.lastIndexOf('/');
let fileName = fileSource.slice(lastIndex + 1, fileSource.length); // gives burn.jpg
let imageSource  = 'appscripts/imgs/pic_library/' + fileName;

console.log(imageSource); // gives appscripts/imgs/pic_library/burn.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can create a jQuery plugin, i.e: `$(...).imagify()`
- Use a regex to replace that pattern: `.replace(/(\.){1,2}\//g, '')`

```js
$.fn.imagify = function() {  
    var src = this.attr('src') || '';
    this.attr('src', src.replace(/(\.){1,2}\//g, ''));
};

$('img').imagify();

$('img').each((_, obj) => console.log($(obj).attr('src')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='../../../../../appscripts/imgs/pic_library/burn.jpg'>
<img src='../appscripts/imgs/pic_library/burn.jpg'>
<img src='./../../appscripts/imgs/pic_library/burn.jpg'>
```

## Resource

- [How to Create a Basic Plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping me out.
I finally solved this using `imgName.split('/appscripts/');`

Like this:

```
var replaceImg = image.split('/appscripts/');
var finalImageName = "../../../appscripts/"+replaceImg[1];
```

Thank you again!